# C++ better way than switch case and return trait function

Tags: c++, coding-style, traits

I'm learning to use traits in C++ and I'm wondering if there is any chance to improve this code. I don't like the switch statement just to pass in the different enum values as a template parameter. I'm explicitly not asking to show different possibilities to write this code in another way, especially not without traits since I choose this for learning.

```cpp
template < FooEnum p >
struct operator_selector {
    template < typename T >
    static bool compare(const T&, const T&) {
        return false;
    }
};

template<>
struct operator_selector< FooEnum::EQ > {
    template < typename T >
    static bool compare(const T& a, const T&b) {
        return a == b;
    }
};

// ...

template < typename T >
std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> select_operator(const FooEnum p) {
    switch (p) {
        case FooEnum::EQ:
            return operator_selector<FooEnum::EQ>::compare<T>;
        case FooEnum::NE:
            return operator_selector<FooEnum::NE>::compare<T>;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to bridge compile-time template values with run-time arguments, you will have to write a switch (or conditional operator). There is no other way.

Comment: Are you willing to inject a bit of macro jank in your codebase, or do you want to stick to "clean" c++ code? There is something to be done here with X-Macros here.

Comment: > "I'm explicitly not asking to show different possibilities to write this code in another way."


What are you looking for then, if not a rewrite without the switch?

Comment: @AndyG I thought that there is maybe a way to tell the compiler to do what I did with the switch

Comment: @Frank do you have a link for that?

Comment: @whymatter: There is, it's the switch statement you wrote :-) That, or a macro. Or some code generator that generates the switch. A better question for StackOverflow might be how to get the same performance or something with more concise code.

Comment: @AndyG I am sorry that my question does not fit your desired answer :-) However, if you have a fancy idea you want to share please feel free to do so!

Comment: @Frank no, there is no need for X macro or Boost.Preprocessor (which is better than home-brew X macros).

Comment: @whymatter just say no to complicated macro-based systems. They are impossible to debug, result in incomprehensible compiler messages and earn bad karma every time someone else has to troubleshoot your code (or understand what it does). Just DON'T DO IT.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
template <
    typename T, 
    typename Res = std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)>
>
Res select_operator(const FooEnum p) {
    static Res ops[] = {
        operator_selector<FooEnum::EQ>::compare<T>,
        operator_selector<FooEnum::NE>::compare<T>,
        ...
    };
    return ops[p];
}
```

implied that your enum starts with `0` and the consecutive values are increased by `1`.